# Unable to scrape the beginning of different events from a table of a webpage using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I've been trying to scrape event times from the table of this [webpage](https://opensea.io/collection/critterznft?tab=activity&search%5BisSingleCollection%5D=true&search%5BeventTypes%5D%5B0%5D=AUCTION_SUCCESSFUL&search%5BeventTypes%5D%5B1%5D=OFFER_ENTERED) using requests module. I have had success scraping timestamp of events from there but can't figure out how to convert them to seconds or minutes.

The following image shows the beginning of the event that I want to capture from that table.

[image]

This is how I've tried with:

```
import requests

link = 'https://api.opensea.io/graphql/'
payload = {"id":"EventHistoryQuery","query":"query EventHistoryQuery(\n  $archetype: ArchetypeInputType\n  $bundle: BundleSlug\n  $collections: [CollectionSlug!]\n  $categories: [CollectionSlug!]\n  $chains: [ChainScalar!]\n  $eventTypes: [EventType!]\n  $cursor: String\n  $count: Int = 16\n  $showAll: Boolean = false\n  $identity: IdentityInputType\n) {\n  ...EventHistory_data_L1XK6\n}\n\nfragment AccountLink_data on AccountType {\n  address\n  config\n  isCompromised\n  user {\n    publicUsername\n    id\n  }\n  ...ProfileImage_data\n  ...wallet_accountKey\n  ...accounts_url\n}\n\nfragment AssetCell_asset on AssetType {\n  collection {\n    name\n    id\n  }\n  name\n  ...AssetMedia_asset\n  ...asset_url\n}\n\nfragment AssetCell_assetBundle on AssetBundleType {\n  assetQuantities(first: 2) {\n    edges {\n      node {\n        asset {\n          collection {\n            name\n            id\n          }\n          name\n          ...AssetMedia_asset\n          ...asset_url\n          id\n        }\n        relayId\n        id\n      }\n    }\n  }\n  name\n  slug\n}\n\nfragment AssetMedia_asset on AssetType {\n  animationUrl\n  backgroundColor\n  collection {\n    displayData {\n      cardDisplayStyle\n    }\n    id\n  }\n  isDelisted\n  imageUrl\n  displayImageUrl\n}\n\nfragment AssetQuantity_data on AssetQuantityType {\n  asset {\n    ...Price_data\n    id\n  }\n  quantity\n}\n\nfragment CollectionLink_assetContract on AssetContractType {\n  address\n  blockExplorerLink\n}\n\nfragment CollectionLink_collection on CollectionType {\n  name\n  ...collection_url\n  ...verification_data\n}\n\nfragment EventHistory_data_L1XK6 on Query {\n  assetEvents(after: $cursor, bundle: $bundle, archetype: $archetype, first: $count, categories: $categories, collections: $collections, chains: $chains, eventTypes: $eventTypes, identity: $identity, includeHidden: true) {\n    edges {\n      node {\n        assetBundle @include(if: $showAll) {\n          relayId\n          ...AssetCell_assetBundle\n          ...bundle_url\n          id\n        }\n        assetQuantity {\n          asset @include(if: $showAll) {\n            relayId\n            assetContract {\n              ...CollectionLink_assetContract\n              id\n            }\n            ...AssetCell_asset\n            ...asset_url\n            collection {\n              ...CollectionLink_collection\n              id\n            }\n            id\n          }\n          ...quantity_data\n          id\n        }\n        relayId\n        eventTimestamp\n        eventType\n        offerExpired\n        customEventName\n        ...utilsAssetEventLabel\n        devFee {\n          asset {\n            assetContract {\n              chain\n              id\n            }\n            id\n          }\n          quantity\n          ...AssetQuantity_data\n          id\n        }\n        devFeePaymentEvent {\n          ...EventTimestamp_data\n          id\n        }\n        fromAccount {\n          address\n          ...AccountLink_data\n          id\n        }\n        price {\n          quantity\n          quantityInEth\n          ...AssetQuantity_data\n          id\n        }\n        endingPrice {\n          quantity\n          ...AssetQuantity_data\n          id\n        }\n        seller {\n          ...AccountLink_data\n          id\n        }\n        toAccount {\n          ...AccountLink_data\n          id\n        }\n        winnerAccount {\n          ...AccountLink_data\n          id\n        }\n        ...EventTimestamp_data\n        id\n        __typename\n      }\n      cursor\n    }\n    pageInfo {\n      endCursor\n      hasNextPage\n    }\n  }\n}\n\nfragment EventTimestamp_data on AssetEventType {\n  eventTimestamp\n  transaction {\n    blockExplorerLink\n    id\n  }\n}\n\nfragment Price_data on AssetType {\n  decimals\n  imageUrl\n  symbol\n  usdSpotPrice\n  assetContract {\n    blockExplorerLink\n    chain\n    id\n  }\n}\n\nfragment ProfileImage_data on AccountType {\n  imageUrl\n  address\n}\n\nfragment accounts_url on AccountType {\n  address\n  user {\n    publicUsername\n    id\n  }\n}\n\nfragment asset_url on AssetType {\n  assetContract {\n    address\n    chain\n    id\n  }\n  tokenId\n}\n\nfragment bundle_url on AssetBundleType {\n  slug\n}\n\nfragment collection_url on CollectionType {\n  slug\n}\n\nfragment quantity_data on AssetQuantityType {\n  asset {\n    decimals\n    id\n  }\n  quantity\n}\n\nfragment utilsAssetEventLabel on AssetEventType {\n  isMint\n  eventType\n}\n\nfragment verification_data on CollectionType {\n  isMintable\n  isSafelisted\n  isVerified\n}\n\nfragment wallet_accountKey on AccountType {\n  address\n}\n","variables":{"archetype":None,"bundle":None,"collections":["critterznft"],"categories":None,"chains":None,"eventTypes":["AUCTION_SUCCESSFUL","OFFER_ENTERED"],"cursor":None,"count":16,"showAll":True,"identity":None}}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36',
    'x-signed-query': '53ff23d0333e3997651740e18c7ea66da6f29fcc5e4d5aacd302574209e44e56',
}

res = requests.post(link,json=payload,headers=headers)
for item in res.json()['data']['assetEvents']['edges']:
    event_time = item['node']['eventTimestamp']
    print(event_time)
```

Current output are like:

```
2022-01-06T15:11:05.010779
2022-01-06T14:58:44
2022-01-06T14:53:07.718379
2022-01-06T14:53:07.775447
```

Expected output:

```
1 minute ago
1 minute ago
2 minutes ago
2 minutes ago
```

> How can I grab the beginning of different events from the table of that webpage using requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this answers your question:

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


link = 'https://api.opensea.io/graphql/'
payload = {"id":"EventHistoryQuery","query":"query EventHistoryQuery(\n  $archetype: ArchetypeInputType\n  $bundle: BundleSlug\n  $collections: [CollectionSlug!]\n  $categories: [CollectionSlug!]\n  $chains: [ChainScalar!]\n  $eventTypes: [EventType!]\n  $cursor: String\n  $count: Int = 16\n  $showAll: Boolean = false\n  $identity: IdentityInputType\n) {\n  ...EventHistory_data_L1XK6\n}\n\nfragment AccountLink_data on AccountType {\n  address\n  config\n  isCompromised\n  user {\n    publicUsername\n    id\n  }\n  ...ProfileImage_data\n  ...wallet_accountKey\n  ...accounts_url\n}\n\nfragment AssetCell_asset on AssetType {\n  collection {\n    name\n    id\n  }\n  name\n  ...AssetMedia_asset\n  ...asset_url\n}\n\nfragment AssetCell_assetBundle on AssetBundleType {\n  assetQuantities(first: 2) {\n    edges {\n      node {\n        asset {\n          collection {\n            name\n            id\n          }\n          name\n          ...AssetMedia_asset\n          ...asset_url\n          id\n        }\n        relayId\n        id\n      }\n    }\n  }\n  name\n  slug\n}\n\nfragment AssetMedia_asset on AssetType {\n  animationUrl\n  backgroundColor\n  collection {\n    displayData {\n      cardDisplayStyle\n    }\n    id\n  }\n  isDelisted\n  imageUrl\n  displayImageUrl\n}\n\nfragment AssetQuantity_data on AssetQuantityType {\n  asset {\n    ...Price_data\n    id\n  }\n  quantity\n}\n\nfragment CollectionLink_assetContract on AssetContractType {\n  address\n  blockExplorerLink\n}\n\nfragment CollectionLink_collection on CollectionType {\n  name\n  ...collection_url\n  ...verification_data\n}\n\nfragment EventHistory_data_L1XK6 on Query {\n  assetEvents(after: $cursor, bundle: $bundle, archetype: $archetype, first: $count, categories: $categories, collections: $collections, chains: $chains, eventTypes: $eventTypes, identity: $identity, includeHidden: true) {\n    edges {\n      node {\n        assetBundle @include(if: $showAll) {\n          relayId\n          ...AssetCell_assetBundle\n          ...bundle_url\n          id\n        }\n        assetQuantity {\n          asset @include(if: $showAll) {\n            relayId\n            assetContract {\n              ...CollectionLink_assetContract\n              id\n            }\n            ...AssetCell_asset\n            ...asset_url\n            collection {\n              ...CollectionLink_collection\n              id\n            }\n            id\n          }\n          ...quantity_data\n          id\n        }\n        relayId\n        eventTimestamp\n        eventType\n        offerExpired\n        customEventName\n        ...utilsAssetEventLabel\n        devFee {\n          asset {\n            assetContract {\n              chain\n              id\n            }\n            id\n          }\n          quantity\n          ...AssetQuantity_data\n          id\n        }\n        devFeePaymentEvent {\n          ...EventTimestamp_data\n          id\n        }\n        fromAccount {\n          address\n          ...AccountLink_data\n          id\n        }\n        price {\n          quantity\n          quantityInEth\n          ...AssetQuantity_data\n          id\n        }\n        endingPrice {\n          quantity\n          ...AssetQuantity_data\n          id\n        }\n        seller {\n          ...AccountLink_data\n          id\n        }\n        toAccount {\n          ...AccountLink_data\n          id\n        }\n        winnerAccount {\n          ...AccountLink_data\n          id\n        }\n        ...EventTimestamp_data\n        id\n        __typename\n      }\n      cursor\n    }\n    pageInfo {\n      endCursor\n      hasNextPage\n    }\n  }\n}\n\nfragment EventTimestamp_data on AssetEventType {\n  eventTimestamp\n  transaction {\n    blockExplorerLink\n    id\n  }\n}\n\nfragment Price_data on AssetType {\n  decimals\n  imageUrl\n  symbol\n  usdSpotPrice\n  assetContract {\n    blockExplorerLink\n    chain\n    id\n  }\n}\n\nfragment ProfileImage_data on AccountType {\n  imageUrl\n  address\n}\n\nfragment accounts_url on AccountType {\n  address\n  user {\n    publicUsername\n    id\n  }\n}\n\nfragment asset_url on AssetType {\n  assetContract {\n    address\n    chain\n    id\n  }\n  tokenId\n}\n\nfragment bundle_url on AssetBundleType {\n  slug\n}\n\nfragment collection_url on CollectionType {\n  slug\n}\n\nfragment quantity_data on AssetQuantityType {\n  asset {\n    decimals\n    id\n  }\n  quantity\n}\n\nfragment utilsAssetEventLabel on AssetEventType {\n  isMint\n  eventType\n}\n\nfragment verification_data on CollectionType {\n  isMintable\n  isSafelisted\n  isVerified\n}\n\nfragment wallet_accountKey on AccountType {\n  address\n}\n","variables":{"archetype":None,"bundle":None,"collections":["critterznft"],"categories":None,"chains":None,"eventTypes":["AUCTION_SUCCESSFUL","OFFER_ENTERED"],"cursor":None,"count":16,"showAll":True,"identity":None}}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36',
    'x-signed-query': '53ff23d0333e3997651740e18c7ea66da6f29fcc5e4d5aacd302574209e44e56',
}

now = datetime.now()

res = requests.post(link,json=payload,headers=headers)
for item in res.json()['data']['assetEvents']['edges']:
    event_time = item['node']['eventTimestamp']
    event_time = event_time.replace("T", " ")
    event_time = event_time[0:19]
    event_time = datetime.strptime(event_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    time_difference = now - event_time
    minutes = int(time_difference.total_seconds() / 60.0)
    print(f'{minutes} minutes ago')
```

Comment: What are the type of results you get when you run the script? I get `363 minutes ago`,`363 minutes ago`,`363 minutes ago` e.t.c. Is it probably because I'm at `gmt + 6`? If I subtract 6 hours from the result, it is very close to the result displayed on that site.

Comment: Hi, tbh I didn't account for that, but indeed, my results also show 100+ minutes (and I am GMT +2). It might indeed be the time difference.

Comment: Also, if you want to take seconds into account as well, you can change `minutes` to `minutes = "{:.2f}".format(float(time_difference.total_seconds() / 60.0))`